# Unable to pass SessionVariable to other flow Mule

Tags: java, session, session-variables, mule

I'ma using Mule Community Edition 3.4.0 and I have a problem during setting/getting a session variable between flows. 
I have a flow in which there is an UntilSuccessful component; when an exception occurs I use an interceptor to save the exception name in a session variable in order to read it in another flow. The problem is that when I attempt to retry the session variable, I get a null value. I really don't know why. 
Here below you can see the mule config file:

```xml
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="OS_Bean_id" name="OS_Bean" class="org.mule.util.store.QueuePersistenceObjectStore"/>

        <spring:bean id="myExceptionHandler_id" class="it.aizoon.prova.ManageException" name="myExceptionHandler"/>

        <spring:bean id="handleException_id" name="handleException" class="it.aizoon.prova.exception.CustomSoapFaultInInterceptor"/>

        <spring:bean id="handleSysError_id" name="handleSysError" class="it.aizoon.prova.exception.CustomInInterceptor"/>
        <spring:bean id="BeanCheckProperty_id" name="BeanCheckProperty" class="it.aizoon.prova.utilities.CheckProperty"/>
    </spring:beans>
    <http:endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="service/prova" method="POST" name="HTTP" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <vm:endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="myQueue" name="myQueue" doc:name="VM"/>
    <queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy name="Queued_Asynchronous_Processing_Strategy" doc:name="Queued Asynchronous Processing Strategy">
        <file-queue-store/>
    </queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy>

<flow name="myFlow" doc:name="myFlow" processingStrategy="Queued_Asynchronous_Processing_Strategy">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"  doc:name="VM" ref="myQueue"/>
        <logger  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="EEEEE: #[exception]"/>
        <processor ref="BeanCheckProperty"/>
        <set-payload value="The request cannot be processed, the error is #[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="500" doc:name="Property"/>
        <logger message="PAYLOAD_VM: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>

<flow name="ProvaRepeatFlow1" doc:name="ProvaRepeatFlow1" processingStrategy="Queued_Asynchronous_Processing_Strategy">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="TalendJob" repeatInterval="5000" repeatCount="0" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job>
                <quartz:payload>error</quartz:payload>
            </quartz:event-generator-job>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <until-successful objectStore-ref="OS_Bean" maxRetries="2" secondsBetweenRetries="2" doc:name="Until Successful"  >
            <flow-ref name="CallWebService" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        </until-successful>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                  <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="myQueue" doc:name="VM"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="CallWebService" doc:name="CallWebService">
        <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
            <cxf:jaxws-client operation="getCode" clientClass="it.aizoon.prova.client.ProvaService" port="ProvaPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
                <cxf:inInterceptors>
                    <!-- <spring:ref bean="handleSysError"/> -->
                </cxf:inInterceptors>

                <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
                    <spring:ref bean="handleException"/>
                </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>

                <cxf:outInterceptors/>

                <cxf:outFaultInterceptors/>
            </cxf:jaxws-client>
            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" path="mockProvaServiceSoapBinding" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        </processor-chain>
</sub-flow>
```

As you can see I have a SOAP component. If there is a SOAP Fault, I'am able to intercept it and save its name in the session variable called EXCEPTION. Here there is the interceptor code:

```
public class CustomSoapFaultInInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor{

      public CustomSoapFaultInInterceptor() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(Phase.INVOKE);
        //getAfter().add(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.class.getName());
      }

      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("InFaultInterceptor_CONTENUTO ECCEZIONE: " + message.getContent(Exception.class));
            System.out.println("InFaultInterceptor_CONTENUTO EVENTO MULE: " + message.getExchange().get(CxfConstants.MULE_EVENT));

            MuleEvent muleEvent = (MuleEvent) message.getExchange().get(CxfConstants.MULE_EVENT);
            MuleMessage muleMessage = muleEvent.getMessage();

            if((message.getContent(Exception.class)) instanceof ParideExec_Exception){
                  ParideExec_Exception parideExec = (ParideExec_Exception) message.getContent(Exception.class);

                  String exceptionName = message.getContent(Exception.class).getClass().getName();
                  //context.getRegistry().registerObject("Eccezione", exceptionName);
                  muleEvent.setSessionVariable("CustomExec", exceptionName);
                  System.out.println("ID SESSIONE: " + muleEvent.getSession().getId());
            }
      }
}
```

And here ther's the java code that read the session variable in another flow.

```
public class CheckProperty implements MessageProcessor{

      @Override
      public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("PPPP: " + event.getSessionVariable("CustomExec"));
            System.out.println("ID SESSIONE: " + event.getSession().getId());

            if(event.getSessionVariable("CustomExec") != null){
                  System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + event.getSessionVariable("CustomExec"));
                  String exceptionName = event.getSessionVariable("CustomExec").toString();
                  event.getMessage().setPayload(exceptionName);
            }
            return event;
}
```

But this variable id null. 
Please, help me. 
I don't know really why Mule has this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the only possibility you have to pass variables among flows when you use the until successful component is to use the MuleContext and in particular to set a variable shared among every flow of every mule applications in the mule context (*event.getMuleContext.getRegistry.registerObject(key,value)*). The only disadvantage is the sharing of this variable but with the right kind of incapsulation you could solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

From the flow information you have provided I could see you are using an Until-successful router to process a call and when an exception occurs you set the exception into session varialbe and then back in the main flow exception strategy you pass it to a vm flow where you retrieve the session variable.

Point 1:   Untill-successful router is an asynchronous processor.
    So the main flow will continue after calling the until-successful router. 
    So the session variable passed from until-successful(sub-flow) is never going to reach the main flow.

```
 <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

You can see that from the logger you have in your catch-exception strategy in the main flow. It prints out all the properties from all scopes in the log. There you will not find your session variable. So it is not being passed from until-successful to your main exception strategy.

More details about Until-Successful at the below link.

[Mule Routing Message Processors](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-UntilSuccessful)

Comment: Thank you for reply. But How can I get that session variable from outside the until-successful component? It should be a way...

Comment: If you use until-successful, then I guess no way, as it is asynchronous.